# Weibull probability plot with R and plotly

Tags: r, plotly, probability, weibull

I'm attempting to build a Weibull probability plot with R and plotly, but have been unable to set the y-axis values correctly (i.e. the plotted markers don't correspond with the positions given in the example below).

```
library(plotly)

time <- c(30, 49, 82, 90, 96)
probability <- c(0.0976, 0.2533, 0.4102, 0.5673, 0.7243)
datum <- c(3.007, 3.777, 4.754, 5.941, 7.472, 9.300, 9.382, 11.811, 14.991, 18.854, 20.968, 
           23.728, 29.874, 29.924, 37.717, 47.534, 60.232, 76.910, 78.034, 94.931, 98.347, 
           124.650, 155.927, 195.327, 245.654)
unreliability <- c(0.0010, 0.0016, 0.0025, 0.0040, 0.0064, 0.0100, 0.0102, 0.0162, 0.0256,
                   0.0405, 0.0500, 0.0638, 0.0996, 0.1000, 0.1538, 0.2336, 0.3453, 0.4906,
                   0.5000, 0.6321, 0.6584, 0.8193, 0.9344, 0.9869, 0.9990)

log_prob <- log(1/(1-probability))
log_unrel <- log(1/(1-unreliability))

probPlot <- plot_ly(x=time, y=log_prob, type='scatter', mode='markers', showlegend=FALSE) %>%
  
  layout(xaxis = list(type='log'), yaxis = list(type='log')) %>%
  
  add_trace(x=datum, y=log_unrel, mode='lines', 
            marker=list(color='transparent'))

probPlot
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you're trying to do here? You have a plot with `time` on the x-axis and `log_prob` on the y-axis, and then you add a trace with `datum` on the x-axis and `log_unrel` on the y-axis. I'm having difficulty imagining how you want to overlay one on to the other or what you want the axis labels to be.

Comment: `time` and `probability` give the probability data and `datum` and `unreliability` give the Weibull fit (fit of the data). The x-axis is on a log scale, and the y-axis is on a log-log scale.  I'm taking the log of `probability` and `unreliability` to get `log_prob` and `log_unrel` respectively, and then using the `type='log'` option in the axis layout to do the other log conversions. In concept, the plotted y positions should match the probability values, but they don't. For example, the largest value is ~0.72 but is plotted at ~1.3.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with plotly, but the `p2y()` function from the `WeibullR` package may help. From [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/WeibullR/versions/1.1.10/topics/p2y),

> This applies the inverse Cumulative Distribution function (. . .) It is particularly handy when adding points and lines to plots generated on wblr objects.